# PowerShell running office app in different culture problems

Tags: powershell, ms-office

Here was described how tor run script in different culture 
[Using-Culture](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/583235.aspx)

But it dos not work for com objects.
Example:
If you create excel file with "=1/3" in "A1" cell and try to get value of it 
cell from PS using different culture, the result will be the same

```
function test {
    [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass]$excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
    $excel.visible = $false
    $excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = $false   

    $wbk = $excel.Workbooks.Open("d:\tmp\test.xls")

    $sheeet=$wbk.Worksheets.Item(1)
    $range = $sheeet.Cells.Item(1,1)
    Write-Host $sheeet.Range("A1").Text

    $excel.Quit()
    $wbk = $Null
    $sheeet = $Null
    $range = $Null
    $excel = $Null
    [GC]::Collect()     
}

Using-Culture -Culture en-US -Script {test} # 0,333333 But expect 0.333333
Using-Culture -Culture ru-RU -Script {test} # 0,333333
```

Long story short, **how tor run office app in different culture?**
Thx!

Conditions: Windows Xp SP3, Office 2003, PowerShell 2.0

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this way

```
$value = $sheeet.Range("A1").Value()
$value.ToString([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("ru-ru"))
```

In fact $value with COM marshalling is a double, so you can put it as a string in any language you want.

Comment: Thx JPBlanc, but you describing on of the methods how to get value in certain locale.

Comment: In general I have Word document linked to Excel sheet, which contains alot of local related data. And I need to write PS script that can update links in this Doc and result should not depend on user locale settings.

Comment: Sorry @Push but $value is a double, and a double is not localized. It begin to be localalized when you put it in a string, that just whant to demonstrate. In spite of using "ru-ru" you can get the computer localization.